# rails, activerecord callbacks not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a callback that runs `after_update`:

```
after_update :set_state

protected

def set_state
  if self.valid?
    self.state = 'complete'
  else
    self.state = 'in_progress'
  end
end
```

But it doesn't actually save those values, why not? Regardless of if the model is valid or not it won't even write anything, even if i remove the `if self.valid?` condition, I can't seem to save the state.

Um, this might sound dumb, do I need to run `save` on it?

---

**update**

Actually, I can't run `save` there because it results in an infinite loop. [sighs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after_update` is run **after** update, so also after save. You can use `update_attribute` to save this value, or just call `save` (I'm not sure if there don't be any recurence). Eventualy you can assign it in `before_update` (list of availble options is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)). On the other side invalid object will not be saved anyway, so why you want to assign here the `state`?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fact that the examples in ActiveRecord documentation do things like this:

```
def before_save(record)
  record.credit_card_number = encrypt(record.credit_card_number)
end

def after_save(record)
  record.credit_card_number = decrypt(record.credit_card_number)
end
```

you do need to save the record yourself.

Answer (score 1):

after_update works on the object in memory not on the record in the table. To update attributes in the DB do the following

```
after_update :set_state

protected

def set_state
  if self.valid?
    self.update_attribute('state', 'complete')
  else
    self.update_attribute('state', 'in_progress')
  end
end
```